# Metro App Certification

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, app-certification-kit

I am working on a C# Metro app in the Visual Studio 11 Beta. When I run the Windows App Certification Kit my application doesn't show up. What's strange is that other apps I've done *do* show up. I have no answer for why some show up and some don't.

Anyone know what needs to be done in VS or my app to make it visible in the app cert tool?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround for the bug

1. Open powershell Get-AppxPackage > out.txt
2. Open out.txt and look at
3. InstallLocation field of all the apps installed. For the apps whose InstallLocation is blank, do a 
   “Remove-AppxPackage ”

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the release configuration of your application and deploy it (Build -> Deploy Solution).